# pip2.7 in virtualenv: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, virtualenv

I created a virtual environment using this command:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 -m virtualenv venv
```

It mostly works, but using `venv/bin/pip2.7` prints the following warning:

> DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st,
> 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021.
> More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at
> https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
> pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.

regardless of the command options, in both Ubuntu16 and Ubuntu20.

Including the above warning in a product is unacceptable and can only lead to confusion. (The warning is factually incorrect because Ubuntu20 supports Python 2.7 and `pip2.7` through at least 2030. As with all popular programming languages, Python 2.7 is likely to be supported far into the future, until a newer compatible language comes along to supercede it.)

How do I disable the warning?

**Update**

It appears that this is a bug in pip versions 19+. How do I tell `virtualenv` to install pip 18?

Comment: Python (or pip) is Python while Ubuntu is Ubuntu. Why do you mix up Python's lifespan with Ubuntu's?

Comment: @hata Allow me to rephrase that as *How are Python and Ubuntu lifespans connected?* The answer is simple. Ubuntu 20 relies on Python2.7 and promises to support it through 2030. Therefore Python 2.7's lifespan is at least through 2030.

Comment: I don't think Python (Python Software Foundation) has some responsibilities for the policy of Ubuntu (Canonical Ltd.).

Comment: @personal_cloud Do you have an official reference for "_Ubuntu promises to support Python2.7 through 2030_"? According to [this](https://www.activestate.com/blog/ubuntu-to-end-python-2-support/), they've dropped support already back in Apr 2023.

Comment: @wim In the ActiveState link you provided: *While Ubuntu is ending their standard Python 2 maintenance and security updates in April 2023, organizations can still opt for Extended Security Maintenance (ESM)*. Read on and there's some good options for getting Python 2 support after Ubuntu drops it.

Comment: @hata You are correct that Python Software Foundation does not have any responsibilities here. (They have only an opportunity to maintain Python 2 compatibility, which they appear to be ceding to others.) Ubuntu has responsibilities to support their Ubuntu 20 distro, because they promised some customers maintenance through 2030. So if PSF introduces a bug, it is Ubuntu's responsibility to work around that bug, possibly by maintaining older versions of pip. Let me know if there's a better solution.

Comment: If some guy named Jim promises his client Bob that he'll update Python 2.7 until 2030, then do you think that means the Python Software Foundation shouldn't warn everyone else that ***they*** are no longer maintaining it, even if a security issue is found?

Comment: @Joe Absolutely. The Python Software Foundation should communicate their *own* intentions — *in the documentation*. But the "Python 2.7 is no longer maintained" warning displayed to all users is wrong, obnoxious, and not supportive of Python 2.7. Therefore, the bug is that somehow my Ubuntu (which supports Python 2.7 through 2030) picked up pip 19 (which evidently does not support Python 2.7 through 2030).

Comment: @personal_cloud What are you actually expecting, for Ubuntu to patch out the warning? And you keep repeating this claim that Ubuntu supports Python 2.7 through 2030, which is clearly false.

Comment: @personal_cloud Where are you getting your information? On ubuntu.com [release notes for Ubuntu 20](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes#Python3_by_default) it says: _In 20.04 LTS, the python included in the base system is Python 3.8. Python 2.7 has been moved to universe and is not included by default in any new installs._ And I have just verified that a clean Ubuntu 20 installation does not include any Python 2.7 installation. Please provide evidence of your claims, or stop spreading misinformation.

Comment: @wim Good catch. Python 2.7 is not one of the languages included in base install. Neither is Ruby. Both are supported though.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's based on a misconception that Python 2.7 is still being supported by Ubuntu/Canonical.

Comment: Even if Python 2.7 _was_ supported (it's not), the premise of the question would be false anyway because [pip is a 3rd-party project](https://github.com/pypa/pip), it's not part of the Python standard library.

Comment: @wim It says right on the Ubuntu release notes link you posted, *On systems upgraded from previous releases, /usr/bin/python will continue to point to python2 for compatibility.* There you have it. Ubuntu 20 is compatible with Python 2 and supports it too. (Python 3 does neither. But that's another story.) You're right, `pip`'s more recent divergence from Ubuntu 20 requirements is the problem, as I discovered. This fact doesn't *invalidate* the question; it *answers* the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This installs `pip 18.1` in a Python 2.7 environment without printing any warnings:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 -m virtualenv --no-pip venv
git clone https://github.com/pypa/pip.git pip
(cd pip ; git checkout -b 18.1 18.1)
(cd pip ; ../venv/bin/python setup.py install)
venv/bin/pip list
```

Answer (score -3):

it's not a bug. It's a very clear warning and message that you shouldn't be using Python 2.

Python 2 is dead, long live Python 3.

Comment: I'd thought it'd be "Python2 is dead. Long Live Python2"?

Comment: Re: *You shouldn't be using Python 2*. I understand that some people want to kill this or that programming language. However, there is tremendous investment in Python2.7 – in the form of existing software. Let me know if there is a newer language that can run Python 2.7 software. In the meantime, **we should use an environment that our software runs in**. In other words, we should use Python 2.

Comment: Re: *Complain to Ubuntu for not updating...* Please elaborate. Who is saying that Ubuntu is the problem? And so far as I can tell, the problem is that pip *got updated*, not that it *didn't* get updated.